# MySQL select from table with unixtime row, but using datetime in query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a MySQL table, one of rows is filled using current unixtime (let's call it '*unixtime*').
I need to select values, but using datetime format in the query.

For example:

```
SELECT * from test where unixtime>"2017-01-06 12:00" AND unixtime<"2017-01-08 12:14"
```

Note: Datetime range could be different.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint:  `FROM_UNIXTIME()` or `UNIXTIME()`.

Comment: `unixtime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-06 12:00')` - [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, by using FROM_UNIXTIME() in your query. The following query selects from a table called 'testValues' and a Unix time field in the table, which is called 'timevalue' (stored as an int). It selects between two date ranges with the ranges in DateTime format in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM testValues
where FROM_UNIXTIME(timevalue) > "2017-01-07 21:00:48" 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timevalue) < "2017-01-07 21:02:09"
```

Hope that helps :)